# hql query with aggregation and grouping

Tags: java, hql

Faced such a problem that I can not understand how I can bypass the group by some field from select

```
@Query("SELECT new value.Value " +
            "(SUM(p.t1), SUM(p.t2), p.t4, SUM(p.t5), p.t6, p.t7) " +
            "FROM P p " +
            "WHERE p.tId = :tId " +
            "GROUP BY p.t4, p.t6, p.t7 ")
```

I don't want to group by two parameters (p.t4, p.t6) but the compiler forces when aggregating
p.t4, p.t6, p.t7 - they are String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select aggregated and non-aggregated fields in the same query, you must group by all non-aggregated values. This is a requirement of many SGBDR also in pure SQL.

This is so in order to make sure to have a single value in the non-aggregated field. Imagine that you have this very simple table:

| Student | Branch | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Physics | 80 |
| Bob | Physics | 75 |
| Bob | Chemistry | 55 |

IF you make this query:

```
select student, branch, avg(grade) 
from table
group by student
```

IN the result, you will get Alice/80 and Bob/65, but what do you expect in the branch field ?
You must change your query whether to aggregate also on the branch field, for example by concatenating the strings, or by grouping also on the branch field so to have separate results for each branch.

Some SGBDR, most notably MySQL and MariaDB, silently accept such queries and return the first value or a random one, but if you are strict, random results aren't acceptable. The same query on the same data must always return the same result.

Note that grouping by additional fields shouldn't cause any trouble if your query is made so that only one value is possible.

Comment: i understand that, but how can fix it ?

Comment: You must change your query to whether only select aggregated values, or add all non-aggregated values in the group by clause. Specificity for HQL: if you select an entire object, you may need to manually add all fields of that object in the group by clause.

Comment: thanks! I just thought that there is some way to make a kind of stub for the attributes in the select, so that group by does not need to be added to group by